# View .NET CLR Error detail in RpcException

Tags: c#, .net, grpc

I am developing a gRPC application with .NET Framework.

When testing the server, an exception is being thrown in my code somewhere. No detail is included, which is making it EXTREMELY difficult to debug, since I have no idea where the error is coming from.

Is there any way that I can view the internal CLR error for debugging purposes (obviously not in production)?

#### EDIT:

The exception is being thrown on the server side, however I am testing as a client with a self-hosted server. As a result, all exceptions are caught by gRPC, and passed to the 'client' (same process) as a vanilla `RpcException`, without any internal details.

Comment: no inner exception? stack trace? message? yes, debugging RPC glitches can be painful, but: what are you seeing? it is hard to advise on what to add without that

Comment: The RpcException in the test client merely says 'Exception was thrown by handler' (I am using Visual Studio Test Project).

Comment: Debug > Windows > Exception Settings to force the debugger to stop when the exception is thrown.

Comment: @JeremyMorren and there's no `.InnerException`?

Comment: hmmm, actually, it looks like it is coming from here https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/3f5912d04a143ccccaf75627906385b111c1a3f7/src/csharp/Grpc.Core/Internal/ServerCallHandler.cs#L314 - which is server side - looks like the server is faulting?

Comment: If you're getting "Exception was thrown by handler" that means that you're server-side handler has thrown an exceptions (which it is not supposed to do) and that exception has been caught by the gRPC framework and turned into an RPC error.
Note that uncaught exception details from the server cannot be sent over the wire for security reasons.
You need to catch the exception in youre server side handler yourself and handle it accordingly.

Comment: Btw, the server has probably logged an error message (about server side handler throwing an exception) - see https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/3f5912d04a143ccccaf75627906385b111c1a3f7/src/csharp/Grpc.Core/Internal/ServerCallHandler.cs#L78